# FFMPEG: Overlay two video with audio in single Video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, android, merge, overlay

**Hey, I am trying this command for merge two audio in single video but it merged only and i need overlay it. Here is my code:**

```
String[] complexCommand = {"ffmpeg", "-y", "-i", "/sdcard/videokit/in.mp4", "-i", "/sdcard/videokit/bb.m4a", "-strict", "experimental", "-filter_complex", "amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=2",/**/ "-shortest", "/sdcard/videokit/out_water.mp4"};
```

**After that I also tried this one for overlay video but after merged video is overlay but only first audio of video comes in this. Here is code:**

```
String[] complexCommands = {"ffmpeg", "-y", "-i", "/sdcard/videokit/in.mp4", "-i", "/sdcard/videokit/tttt.mp4", "-strict", "experimental", "-filter_complex", "[0:v:0]pad=iw*2:ih[bg];" + "[bg][1:v:1]overlay=w", "-s", "320x240", "-r", "30", "-b", "15496k", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "/sdcard/videokit/partik.mp4"};
```

Comment: **Yeah!!! I made it myself with customized code.**

Comment: String[] complexCommand = {"ffmpeg", "-y", "-i", "/sdcard/videokit/g1.mp4",                                            "-i", "/sdcard/videokit/t4.mp4",                                            "-strict", "experimental", "-filter_complex",                                            "[0:v:0]pad=iw*2:ih[bg];" + "[bg][1:v:1]overlay=w,scale=320x240;[0:1]pan=stereo|c0=2*c0|c1=3*c0[a0];[1:a]pan=stereo|c0=1*c0|c1=4*c0[a1];[a0][a1]amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=2",

Comment: "-r", "30", "-b", "15496k", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "-shortest", "/sdcard/videokit/parik.mp4"};

Answer (score 1):

You have to combine the two, like this

```
String[] complexCommands = {"ffmpeg", "-y", "-i", "/sdcard/videokit/in.mp4", "-i", "/sdcard/videokit/tttt.mp4", "-strict", "experimental", "-filter_complex", "[0:v:0]pad=iw*2:ih[bg];[bg][1:v:1]overlay=w,scale=320x240;[0][1]amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=2", "-r", "30", "-b", "15496k", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "-shortest", "/sdcard/videokit/partik.mp4"};
```

Depending on your FFmpeg version, you may have to assign output pads and map them, but try this first.

Comment: not working Please help me

Comment: Edited cmd. Try now.

Comment: Still not working. Also tried [0:1][1:1] amix but since not working. only get first audio of first video. I want to overlay both audio of both video parallel.

Comment: Show the full console output.

Comment: You can paste it in the Q. And the above is the command, not the console output.

Comment: 07/07 16:03:26: Launching ffmpeg4android_demo
$ adb push C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\ffmpeg4android_demo_studio_25_24_9\ffmpeg4android_demo_studio\ffmpeg4android_demo\build\outputs\apk\ffmpeg4android_demo-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.examples.ffmpeg4android_demo
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.examples.ffmpeg4android_demo"
 pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.examples.ffmpeg4android_demo
Success

Comment: $ adb shell am start -D -n "com.examples.ffmpeg4android_demo/com.examples.ffmpeg4android.Main" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Waiting for application to come online: com.examples.ffmpeg4android_demo.test | com.examples.ffmpeg4android_demo
Waiting for application to come online: Waiting for application to come online: com.examples.ffmpeg4android_demo.test | com.examples.ffmpeg4android_demo
Connecting to com.examples.ffmpeg4android_demo
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8609', transport: 'socket'

Comment: Need to see ffmpeg's console output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42154/discussion-between-parik-dhakan-and-mulvya).